# Removing 3-way switches which control outlets

Tags: electrical

I have 2 3-way switches controlling the bottoms of the receptacles in my living room and want to remove switches and put blanks on boxes and leave receptacles always on. I want to do away with both switches.
How can I do this?

Comment: If you remove those switches, will there still be other switches which control a light or receptacle in the room? How will you control lights in that room?

Comment: Are there other light fixtures in said living room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you want to eliminate the switch control of the outlets, if not ignore. If it is wired as most three way switches are you can connect the three wires at each switch together then put a blank cover over the box. You can also connect the identified terminal to one of the travelers and do the same at the other end. Either way will work.Do not mix any other wires with those three.